# Look for MySQL table structure recommendation

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, mysql-5.7

I have two table now:

**conference table**: id, name

[image]

**people table**: people_id, name

[image]

#### what I want to do

I want to make a new table so that I can get all attend people by conference id but also get all conference a specific man attended by people_id.

#### what I have thought

[image]
make a new table whose columns is all the people's id, and insert each conference as row, if the people shows in conference, we make it 1, otherwise 0. But it's too sparse and difficult to show which people attend a specific conference because we have many columns.

## UPDATE

thanks for your comment. Now I create a table like this:

I think it's much better than the table before.

[image]

Comment: Hint: You only need two columns.

Comment: thank you. I have created a table just like what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

A join table called conferences_people.

```
 cp_id | conference_id | people_id
-------+---------------+-----------
 1     | 1234          | 1
 2     | 1234          | 4
 3     | 1234          | 5
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya YES, the people_id is in my original conference table, now I removed it and created a new table with conference_id and people_id.